# Vertical align second paragraph to the top of image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code.  Right now the Title is aligned vertical top of the image.  But the description is still wrapping (blocked) below the image and I want it to also be top aligned, right under the title next to the image like the title is, but again below the title.

```
    .vtop
    {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        float: none;
    }
    .padding-top-bottom-5
    {
       padding-top: 5px !important;
       padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }
    .nopadding 
    {
       padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .inline-block
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }

            <div class="col-lg-9 well margin-top-5 padding-top-bottom-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 well nopadding">
                        <p>
                            <img src="../../../Images/thumbs/206.jpg" class="vtop" />
                            <span class="bold inline-block">Title of Something</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="vtop">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce efficitur fermentum velit, faucibus volutpat diam pretium nec. Praesent quis congue mi. Donec a nibh efficitur, mollis purus at, elementum lorem. Praesent tempor pharetra felis, vel consectetur lectus sodales nec. Suspendisse vel molestie dolor, id tincidunt eros. Mauris et turpis rutrum, sollicitudin augue nec, aliquet nisl. Vestibulum mattis ipsum velit, et convallis est mattis porttitor. Morbi sit amet finibus risus, et maximus neque. Mauris fermentum magna et ligula consectetur lobortis.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.vtop
    {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .padding-top-bottom-5
    {
       padding-top: 5px !important;
       padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }
    .nopadding 
    {
       padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .inline-block
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-9 well margin-top-5 padding-top-bottom-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 well nopadding">
                        <p>
                            <img src="http://www.lastmiracle.com/wp-content/uploads/10/The-engineering-in-Nature-200x200.jpg" class="vtop" />
                            <span class="bold inline-block">Title of Something</span>
                            <br /><br />
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce efficitur fermentum velit, faucibus volutpat diam pretium nec. Praesent quis congue mi. Donec a nibh efficitur, mollis purus at, elementum lorem. Praesent tempor pharetra felis, vel consectetur lectus sodales nec. Suspendisse vel molestie dolor, id tincidunt eros. Mauris et turpis rutrum, sollicitudin augue nec, aliquet nisl. Vestibulum mattis ipsum velit, et convallis est mattis porttitor. Morbi sit amet finibus risus, et maximus neque. Mauris fermentum magna et ligula consectetur lobortis.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I don't wanna use <br>...but let me try your changes without br and put it into paragraphs

Comment: worked I wonder why if I had no float it was pushing the description down

Comment: For a less verbose method of achieving the desired results you should implement the `media object` concept that I posted just now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after the CSS concept called the [media object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/). It's designed specifically for the scenario you mention; a layout as follows:

```
+---------+ ~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~
|         | 
|         | ~~~~~ ~~~~~ ~~~~
|         | ~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~
+---------+
```

You can achieve this with a basic structure:

```
<div class="media">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" class="media__img" />
    <div class="media__body">
        <p>Title of Something.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea sed voluptate unde rerum quasi quidem, praesentium odio. Necessitatibus quo, non unde repudiandae adipisci, et corrupti eius ipsa, tempore ex aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea sed voluptate unde rerum quasi quidem, praesentium odio. Necessitatibus quo, non unde repudiandae adipisci, et corrupti eius ipsa, tempore ex aut.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And just a few lines of CSS:

```
.media { display: block }

.media__img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 24px
}

.media__body {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

[Here is a working fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/mde4fymr/).

Comment: Why are you specifying `display: block` on `<div>` elements when that is the default?

Comment: @steveax – you're right, it's not necessary, just a matter of preference. In some cases I prefer to be explicit for consistency's sake. For example, if I were working with another dev they might by tempted to use `span` on the media body if its content is very short, thus breaking the layout. But, as you rightly point out, in the example above it isn't essential.

Answer (score 0):

You know there's always so many ways to solve problems. It seems to me it was a bit harder for me to understand what exactly was going on since you left out a lot of css info for the rest of the tags, but as far as I can see I feel like you're doing a lot of work to potentially do something quite simple. Hopefully that's not being to harsh I commend your efforts! I left your tags that aren't referenced in the css so it won't break you're code and you can paste it in easily.

All you need to do is float the image left `.floatLeft` and then create a div beside it with a margin-left to push the `.content` div containing the title/paragraph below out from the floated div since floats don't hold "real" space in the content flow of a web site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .vtop
                {
                    display: inline-block;
                    vertical-align: top;
                    float: none;
                }
                .padding-top-bottom-5
                {
                   padding-top: 5px !important;
                   padding-bottom: 5px !important;
                }
                .nopadding 
                {
                   padding: 0 !important;
                }
                .inline-block
                {
                    display: inline-block;
                }

            .floatLeft {
                float:left;
                }

            .content {
                margin-left:210px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="col-lg-9 well">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 well nopadding">
                    <img class="floatLeft" src="http://www.lastmiracle.com/wp-content/uploads/10/The-engineering-in-Nature-200x200.jpg" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <p><span class="bold inline-block">Title of Something</span></p>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce efficitur fermentum velit, faucibus volutpat diam pretium nec. 
                        Praesent quis congue mi. Donec a nibh efficitur, mollis purus at, elementum lorem. Praesent tempor pharetra felis, vel consectetur 
                        lectus sodales nec. Suspendisse vel molestie dolor, id tincidunt eros. Mauris et turpis rutrum, sollicitudin augue nec, aliquet nisl. 
                        Vestibulum mattis ipsum velit, et convallis est mattis porttitor. Morbi sit amet finibus risus, et maximus neque. Mauris fermentum 
                        magna et ligula consectetur lobortis.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```